# YII -How to Delete Related rows from all tables?

Tags: php, yii, cascading-deletes

i have a parent table named "Studio" and many other child  tables having "studio_id" as foreign key .Now i want to delete all the related rows from child tables if the parent record is deleted.How can this be possible?

Comment: What kind of DBMS you are using (Oracle,MySQL,Sqlite,...) and if MySQL then what engine (Innodb,MyISAM,..)??

Comment: Please see this post hope fully fit code your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/70345130/8425184

Answer (score 4):

Enable  cascading deletes in your schema. The documentation for this is on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: how can i enable cascading deletes? am using innodb