# Delete parent table data when deleted all related child rows form child table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

This is my parent table:-

```
id | name    | created_at
 1 | mobile  |  NULL
 2 | Laptop  |  Null
```

And This is Child table:-

```
id | name  |parent_id| amount | created_at
 1 | Nokia |    1    | 2500   | NULL
 2 |Samsung|    1    | 3500   | Null
 3 |Sony   |    1    | 4000   | Null
```

When I am deleting all child data of related by parent Mobile data using by foreign key then I want to delete also Mobile Data in a parent table.

Comment: Are you using laravel query builder

Comment: @Krishanu yes..

Comment: Then i suggest that you do something like counting the no. of rows in child table with parent_id ,for exapmle, 1. If it is 0 then delete the row from parent table. If you give me a few minutes then i can try out a code myself

Comment: @Krishanu brother but I think MySQL do not provided any functionality for deleting by using child table data for delete parent table row.

Comment: It does. Joins is a great way for it

Comment: @Krishanu ok bro I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code after your delete statement

```
$child = DB::table('child')->where('parent_id',$id)->get();
if($child->count() == 0){
    $parent = DB::table('parent')->where('id', $id)->delete();;
}
```

Make sure you are using Query builder for this

If you are using eloquent, and not DB, then add ..

```
use DB;
```

before the class.

Hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Add this code after your delete statement

```
$parent = DB::table('parent')->find($id);
$child = DB::table('child')->where('parent_id',$id)->get();
if($child->count() == 0){
  $parent = DB::table('parent')->where('id', $id)->delete();
}else{
  $child = DB::table('child')->where('parent_id',$id)->delete();
}
$parent = DB::table('parent')->where('id', $id)->delete();
```

If you are using eloquent, and not DB, then add ..

```
use DB;
```

before the class.